# Hide form in panel on session exist

Tags: session, jquery-mobile

I have a panel opening with a form for login features, all that is working well, after a successful login and a time-out the panel closes.

now, if the user opens the panel again already logged in - I´d like to hide the form until session dies or user logs out.

The session is created in with PHP and I can fetch it and view it.

```
$(document).on("open", "#leftpane", function(e, ui){

        var userExist = "<?PHP echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>";

        if(userExist){
              $("#loginForm").hide();
            }

});
```

As a beginner with JQM I have only figured out that I need to implement some kind of event where I can check for 'panelbeforeopen'? then test if session exist and hide the form.

And that's where I'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: Found this just after my post.. hopefully helps someone else too

    $(document).on("panelbeforeopen", "#leftpane", function(e, ui){
 
 var userExist = "<?PHP echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>";
   
   var disableForm = "<?php echo ($_SESSION['user'] == '' ? 'true' : 'false') ?>";
   
   if(disableForm){
      $("#loginForm").hide();
    }else{
    //do what ever
    }
 
    });

Comment: update: I cant seem to get my "panelbeforeopen" event to fire until I refresh the page once?  anyone got an idea how/where i should implement this in JQM 1.4.1?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `beforeopen` panel event as documented [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeopen).

Comment: @user3329599 - Ok, could you post the code you tried?

Comment: I posted it as another topic here: might be considered a duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913601/jquery-mobile-panel-event-only-triggered-if-placed-in-external-js  plz make a fiddle if possible